# How to merge the values coming from 4 different columns into one fina column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a daframe like the one below:

the columns `str, mpr, cta, mpt` are all the same but for every record I have value in only 1 of these 4 columns.

How can I merge these 4 columns in only 1 like the output below:

```
id     str     mpr     cta      mpt
 1     10      null    null     null
 2    null     11      null     null
 3    null     null    6        null
 4    null     null    null     1
```

Output:

```
id  final
 1   10
 2   11
 3   6
 4   1
```

as you can see the columns `final` will always have a value coming from only one of each 4 columns.

Important:  sometimes the 4 columns is null then the `final` column will also be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# find the max along the row, starting from second columns (skipping over ID)
df['final']=df.iloc[:,1:].max(axis=1, numeric_only=True) #.astype(int)
df[['id','final']]

# if a row can have all Null than don't add astype(int)
```

```
   id   final
0   1    10
1   2    11
2   3     6
3   4     1
```

Comment: it returnas a warning: `FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction` the the result I get all NaN in final column

Comment: does your DF has more columns than listed here?

Comment: or are any of the columns you listed have alphanumeric values?

Comment: yes. I had some non-numeric values.  I just dropped then and then you code worked.  Huge thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Lets call your original DataFrame df and lets say you plan on scaling it on a million columns.

Create a list for the final column:

```
Final_List = []
```

Create a list of colums

```
 my_list = df.columns.values.tolist()
    
    for x in range(len(my_list)):
        for y in range(len(df[my_list[x]]):
            if df[my_list[x][y] != 'null'
               final_value = df[my_list[x][y]]
               Final_List.append(final_value) 
               break #breaks the inner loop
            else:
                 final_value = 'nul'
            Final_List.append(final_value)
    
    df["final"] = Final_List
```

Comment: I just edited to code, original post had error in it.